# Axis not displaying integers

Tags: pgfplots

I've built a plot using PGFPlots where I've told it to display axis numbers every 10 units and for some reason instead of picking sensible integers for this it's defaulted to numbers like 109.99, 119.99, 129.99, etc. Is there any way I can get it to use something like 110, 120, 130, etc? I don't want to simply change the precision as this won't change what the number actually is, just how it's displayed, thus introducing a systematic error. Image code below, if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={x},ylabel={y},
    xtick distance=4,minor x tick num=3,
    ytick distance=10,minor y tick num=9,
    width=12.5cm,height=11.69213cm,
    scale only axis=true,
    enlargelimits=false,
    scaled ticks=false,]
    \addplot graphics[xmin=37477.82905, xmax=37501.72688, ymin=37407.02447, ymax=37509.41263,] {example-image};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*edit* I've managed to achieve the desired behaviour by adding the below line to the axis code, which explicitly states where every y-axis number should be. My question now becomes, why isn't `pgfplots` picking these numbers as the most sensible choice, and is there an easier way to do this?

```
ytick={37400,37410,37420,37430,37440,37450,37460,37470,37480‌​,37490,37500,37510},
```

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have the `image` so we cannot compile your code. Could you modify it so it doesn't produce an error but still shows your issue, please. (And when you are at it, please make it a full working [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` please.

Comment: When I put your code snippet into a minimal document, using `example-image` as the image file, I do get integer values for the ticks, so a complete example that reproduces the problem would be useful.

Comment: Ok, code should now show the issue.

Comment: you could add `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=0}` to the axis options which simply rounds the values. (The minor offset to the "real" rounded number should not be recognizable.)

Comment: Even if that's true in this specific case, it won't be true in general, so I would like to find an alternative.

Comment: I don't think that this is a "general problem", but a (mathematical) rounding issue, so (I think) either my trip from above will help or you should use round values for `xmin` etc. which should also avoid this problem.

Comment: Changing my numbers is not suitable, as it creates inaccuracies. I've found a workaround that uses correct numbers without any inaccuracies by explicitly defining where each major tick is placed with the code `ytick={37400,37410,37420,37430,37440,37450,37460,37470,37480,37490,37500,37510},` This does the job, although is a bit too manual for my liking. I guess what I'm looking for is a setting of some kind that tells it how to pick sensible numbers, or only use integers, or similar.

Comment: add `,yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0}` to axis options

Comment: Changing the precision is not an option as it changes a number like 2.4 to 2, while still being positioned at the 2.4 point, resulting in inaccuracies.

Comment: Just came across this one again. While I think you are in principle right that changing the precision results in accuracies, in this case they are so small that they surely are irrelevant. I mean, the rounding is around 0.001% of the height of the image, isn't it?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. This is just an MWE built to show the issue. It may not be significant in this case, but for others it can be. This issue needs to be resolved in a manner that changes where the main ticks are placed, not simply how their labels are displayed. As per my earlier comment and the edit to the main post, the ````xtick```` and ````ytick```` options achieve the desired outcome, albeit in a particularly clunky manner. I am now seeking a way to automate this if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Bad news: the positions of ticks is calculated by `\pgfplots@assign@default@tick@foraxis` and then stored in `\pgfplots@#1tick` in axis cs. That is, instead of `37400,37410,...,37510`, what is stored is `-1.70305,-0.70305,...,10.73982`.

When [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) is typesetting the labels, these numbers will be transformed back to the data cs and there will be rounding error.

This error is inevitable unless one of the following happens:

- you can improve the precision of FPU; or
- you can redesign the interface so that `\pgfplots@ytick` will hold the `37400,37410,...,37510` instead of `-1.70305,-0.70305,...,10.73982`.

Otherwise, as @percusse mentioned, the only chance is to change the precision and pretend that it does not exists.

---

---

As @Torbjørn T mentioned, the relative error is (37409.99-37410)/37410 = -0.000000267308206 and this is about the limit of FPU.

## How small is this?

Assume that the `axis` is 10cm high then 0.0000003 of 10cm is 0.000003cm, or 0.00003mm, or 0.03μm, or 30nm.

For a iMac 5k (27 inch screen), each pixel is 133945nm.

For a 2400 dpi printer, each dot is 10583nm.

If you `\draw(0,0)rectangle(10,10)`, the side length of this square will be 283.4681bp, which is 1246nm larger than what it should be.

And guess what, the wave length of the visible light is at least 380nm.